# Form on the very left of all screens?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, desktop

I'm working on 2 screens and the **right** screen is my primary screen. Some people do it the other way around with the primary screen. **How can I make my form appear on the very left of all available screens ?**

I can say `Location = new Point(-1920, 0);` on my system and it is fine but at other systems the form might be outside of the desktop area and is not reachable with mouse.

```
// my system
Location = new Point(-1920, 0); // very left

// other systems
Location = new Point(0, 0); // very left
```

Comment: try to get points of Screen and then use those Points to put you screen ACcordingly

Comment: logically your **primary** screen should always be at the **top-left**, all the screens use the same coordinates system with the `(0,0)` being at the top-left of the primary screen.

Comment: @KingKing Right now I'm on WinXP and my left screen has negative coordinates.

Comment: @mini-me have you checked out my answer below?

Comment: @KingKing Yes, it uses Linq.

Comment: @mini-me doesn't it work? using `LINQ` here is just for concise code, the point is using a for-loop to get the min value, it's acceptable because the number of screens is hardly larger than 100, and the for-loop will be very fast even when the number is larger than 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can always use this code to get the `most left` out of all the screens:

```
int mostLeft = Screen.AllScreens.Min(s=>s.Bounds.Left);
//do the same for the most top
int mostTop = Screen.AllScreens.Min(s=>s.Bounds.Top);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to determine the left most screen. After that you can use the Bounds property of this screen to get the desired location.

Use the following code:

```
var leftMostScreen = Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(s => s.Bounds.Left).First();
var leftMostLocation = leftMostScreen.Bounds.Location;
```